# How to be sure that a target goal in a match 3 game level will not be impossible?

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, game-engine

This is clearly not a coding problem but the logical one. I am starting to learn how to make a match 3 game. but there is a question rising in my mind.

when i will set goal to complete the level, how will i know the goal is achievable ?

suppose in a level where i have to collect 5 Red, 12 blue, 9 green objects by matching the same(like farm heros). how would i decide how much moves i need to set to make this goal achievable. i mean it should be challenging but not be impossible.

since the objects spawn in a random whats the surety that there will be enough number of gem in the game to not make impossible.

is there some logical explanation for this, or i just have to test and look out how many moves it takes to achieve the goal.

Is there an algorithm which generates the gems according to target set, or they are generated in random manner?

To be more clear towards my question i am going to take an example of King.com's  [farm-heros-saga](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.king.farmheroessaga&hl=en) .

In level 9 the target is to collect number of four types of objects 26,26,14,5 respectively. and the maximum number of moves are 22.

now this goal may be achievable and challenging(i mean you can achieve it in two or three trials ) but not impossible.

Now my question is what made those guys so sure that it will not be impossible, how they decided that 22 move will be enough and challenging.

well.. they could have put the maximum number of moves to 5 or 6. but that would surely make it impossible to clear the level. so how they decided to keep move 22 or this.

Are they using static pattern to generate and spawn objects, or ratio of collectible gems is fixed(i.e in total gameplay there will be X%,Y%,Z%,M% of gems respectively ), or there is some other way.

I just need some hint what should i look for..

Comment: I think it's a hard problem. Number of state grows so rapidly that it's HARD to trace the state.

Comment: @Fallen : I couldn't understand. would you please explain ?

Comment: By `state` I mean the arrangement of the board at any time. So to solve the problem at any time we need to know how many red, blue and green gems already have been collected and what's the current arrangement of the board.
Now for any possible move at any stage, a new branch of state will be created. If you can't store information about the already visited states the growth of number of states will be huge and untraceable thus making the problem a Hard problem IMHO

Comment: You are using a game who's main purpose is frustration in order to sell power-ups. This is IMHO very **bad** game design. In other words, they probably arrived at that number of moves by testing how many tries on average it takes to complete the goal, then **lowered** that value to 2/3 (or whatever they chose). This way players would fail many times, get frustrated and pay for power-ups in order to progress. The better way would be to do the testing, find the average moves, and then **increase** them by 10-25% (based on difficulty).

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your problem right but I assume:

You have some 'maze' like game board with falling/movable gems or some swap-able gems and after match removal/scoring  'random' gems fill the hole.

then:

1. **backward generating**

   simply generate the level gems backwards. First generate the target solution and then randomly generate `N`-back steps to game level start. This is not doable for random generating of gems but always grants the solution in `N`-steps. The draw back is there is guaranteed only one solution.
2. **semi random gem generation**

   for example this is how **Bejeweled** works. Remember the level state, generate random gems and test if any valid move is possible. if not then generate different random gems. If still not generate another random set ...

   if still no valid move after `N` generations then generate some special gem like hypercube or bomb or joker or what ever. This is simple and always grants playability but not the solution in `N`-moves

Comment: ok so.. for example in farm-heros like match3 puzzle game. how those people decided that in level 6 the target should be collecting number of 3 types  of gems 22,22,20 respectively, in 8 moves. are those guys generating gems randomly. or its already decided that the gems will be generated in a certain pattern always ?