# How to guarantee that a Match 3 game is infinite

Tags: c#, algorithm, puzzle

How does Match 3 developers guarantee that there will always be a possible choice and avoid "No more moves" situations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to be sure that a target goal in a match 3 game level will not be impossible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24952187/2521214)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of times, they just tend to add in a shuffle feature whenever there are no more moves.

Bejeweled is a good example where, in certain modes, the player only has a certain amount of shuffles, and will lose once there are no more moves or shuffles.

Comment: That does not answer the question. Sorry : (